# AJAX returns null?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to get information from my server. the page xxx.php is a page with only 123 written on it. However, when I want to return the content of that page, it returns null.

```
function myFunct(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'xxx.php',
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
}

var data = myFunct(); //nothing.
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Then what should I do? EDIT: Ok, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Why is every single answer wrong? Shouldn't people know how to answer this by now?

Comment: Which is? TJ- solution seems to be working..

Comment: I didn't notice that answer.  He doesn't tell you where to put the callback.

Comment: The answer by @SLaks is more 'complete' because you may define myFunct in a library where processMyData() has not been defined. In your caller js, you call myFunct and pass the callback function, thus decoupling the processing logic from myFunct. Although, that doesn't make the answer 'wrong'.

Comment: I can only accept one answer tho (and I can't upvote yet)... Or I would accept both..! Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that ajax is 'asynchronous'. So, the response to your server call may not received by the time myFunct() completes execution.
You may put the logic of process the data from your server call in the 'success' of ajax.

```
function myFunct(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'xxx.php',
        success: function(data) {
           // processMyData(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please see my comment in your question and why it might be better to use @SLaks answer (Depends on your use case).

Answer (score 5):

AJAX is **asynchronous**.

You only get a response some time **after** the rest of your code finishes running.

Instead, you need to return the value using a callback, just like `$.ajax` does:

```
function myFunct(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'xxx.php',
        success: function(data) {
            // Do something to the data...
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}

myFunct(function(result) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Why create another anonymous function? You could've just written `success: callback` because it takes `data` as it's parameter directly.

Comment: Good point by everyone. This is the best solution, provided that you apply the extra solution provided by @MihaiStancu

Answer (score 1):

You can use in synchronized mode (despite being recommended with async callback to avoid "freezing" of the code).

Using synchronized:

```
function myFunct(callback){
   return $.ajax({
        url: 'xxx.php',
        async: false
    }).responseText;
}
```

Comment: Pretty creative. A brilliant architect once said to not go Async until performance requires it.

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: @MohanPrasad The question and the answer are old (2012, 4 years ago) And in any case at the time I oriented: *despite being recommended with async callback to avoid "freezing" of the code*

Comment: Avoid using synchronized mode, it doesn't work already in Chrome, other browsers will not support it soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
var globalVal;

    function myFunct(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'xxx.php',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data); // you can see you data
                globalVal= data;
            }
        });
    }
```

// it is response to server, and response executed a bit latter that you assign value

```
myFunct(); //nothing.
alert(globalVal)
```

Comment: if you need use 'data', you can pass it to function from success

Comment: 'alert(globalVal)' may not show the intended data. It will be executed immediately after myFunct(). The response may be received much later.

Comment: You can use them at once after ajax request success:function(data){ USE_MY_DATA(data)}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a ajax error handling, for check your response

```
function myFunct(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'xxx.php',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error:  function(jqXHR, textStatus){
       alert("Status: "+ jqXHR.status);
       alert("textStatus: " + textStatus);
    }

});
```

}

Comment: He had stated that it would succeed but "data" would be null, hence; the error is redundant and not required.