# Ajax and async await

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

I am a bit confused as to why my ajax call doesnt return a result. I thought a method defined as async automatically returns a promise. What am I doing wrong?

```
async AjaxCall(filePath) {
      let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.open('POST', filePath, true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhttp.send();

     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
            return xhttp.responseText;
          }
      }
  }


async function Test() {
  var result = await AjaxCall("file.php");
  alert(result);
}

Test();
```

Comment: `AjaxCall` doesn't await anything or return a promise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I promisify native XHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662817/ajax-returns-null)

Comment: if you're looking for ajax+promises, check out the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async`/`await` is (really useful) syntactic sugar for creating and consuming promises. Your `AjaxCall` function implicitly creates a promise, but then also implicitly resolves it immediately with the value `undefined` because you never `await` anything, and the only `return` isn't directly in `AjaxCall` but is instead in the `onreadystatechange` callback.

You *can* wrap a promise around XHR, but you don't have to: [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) already does:

```
async function Test() {
  var result = await fetch("file.php");
  if (result.ok) {
      alert(await result.text());
   }
}
```

But if you want to do it yourself, you'll need to explicitly create and consume a promise rather than using `async` on `AjaxCall`:

```
function AjaxCall(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.open('POST', filePath, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhttp.send();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhttp.status === 200) {
                    resolve(xhttp.responseText);
                } else {
                    reject(); // Probably including some rejection reason
                }
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: WOW that is a great answer. I even learned something new. Never heared of "fetch".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't actually returning any data from your function. You are returning data inside the onreadystatechange function but that is just lost and never used. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969495/in-javascript-how-do-i-should-i-use-async-await-with-xmlhttprequest) specifically this piece of code:

```
function makeRequest(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            } else {
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

You will notice that it has wrapped the entire function in a promise and then you can use the standard async/await functionality when calling it. Async/Await is really just a wrapper around the existing promise functionality.